# Magento 2 Password Reset Email goes to 404 link

Tags: magento2, email-templates, 404, change-password

I am unsure what has happened but my email template Reset Password button now links to a 404 page. Is there any way that I can get the original variable used for getting a customers password reset link?

I can confirm that the email template being called is the correct one as I have previously formatted the template.

The anchor tag currently being used that links to the 404 page is as follows:

```
<a href="{{store url="customer/account/resetpassword/" _query_id=$customer.id _query_token=$customer.rp_token}}"><span>Reset Password</span></a>
```

Comment: What is the url you are getting when click on reset password link from email?

Comment: This one: mySite.co.uk/customer/account/resetpassword/?id=7263254&token=mfuApW6SwLOX4JVtDZHc25ewOD9Wi0Zs I have stripped the first part of the URL up to /customer

Comment: On which email template are you getting this url? Did you customise it or default template? If default template then please let me know the template file name?

Comment: Turns out what I thought was the correct URL (/customer/account/resetpassword) wasn't actually the correct URL. The one I needed was /customer/account/createpassword. I found this by reverting to the default magento email template and that was set as a different link. Its always the small things that break :D

Comment: You are absolutely right. I have checked the email template file and its shows like this <a href="{{var this.getUrl($store,'customer/account/createPassword',[_query:[id:$customer.id,token:$customer.rp_token],_nosid:1])}}" target="_blank">{{trans "Set a New Password"}}</a>

Comment: Well i'm glad that turned out to be something small. Appreciate your help, happy coding :)

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: just a small change 'customer/account/createpassword' P word in password should be small.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a transactional email template (reset password) using the [Postcards](https://designmodo.com/postcards/). I hope this resource will be helpful.

Also, you can download free email templates from [GitHub](https://github.com/designmodo/html-email-templates).